# SP13: Calendar Permission Groups

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, calendar

I have a calendar that I created in SP13.  I would like to add others from a different site collection to the calendar.  However, when I go to list settings > permissions that particular group name does not appear within the drop down box. Is there a way to add that permissions group that's located in a different site collection to my calendar?  Or should I recreate the calendar within the other site collection that has the permission groups I want.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way from my point of view is to add the users to an Active Directory Group. Then assign this AD group the requested permissions on the calendar and on the other site collection.